# Seeking proper terminology for subset coefficient

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, terminology

I understand Jaccard similarity coefficient / Jaccard index is a metric for comparing similarity for two sets.

I am looking for a numeric coefficient to measure the extent to which A is a subset of B. I am thinking of:

$$\frac{| A \cap B |}{| A |}$$

I have spent a lot of time googling, but have not found any references to a subset measurement index like this.

Q: Is there a proper term for this?

Q: Is there a preferred formula/method for quantifying some type of "subset index" ?